# Sequelize get values from belongsTo relationship

Tags: mysql, node.js, npm, sequelize.js

I am creating an app using an existing database in Mysql. 
I can retrieve the values from the tables, but when I try to retrieve the values from associate models, doesn't work.

Purchase Order model:

```
"use strict";

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var PurchaseOrder = sequelize.define('purchase_orders' , {
    id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
    field: 'id'
  },
  purchaseDate: {
    type: DataTypes.DATE,
    allowNull: true,
    field: 'purchase_date'
  },
  supplierId: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
    allowNull: true,
  //  references: {
//      model: 'suppliers',
//      key: 'id'
//    },
    field: 'supplier_id'
  },
  requestedById: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
    allowNull: true,
    field: 'requested_by_id'
  },
  masterPurchaseOrderId: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
    allowNull: true,
//    references: {
//      model: 'master_purchase_orders',
//      key: 'id'
//    },
    field: 'master_purchase_order_id'
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: DataTypes.DATE,
    allowNull: false,
    field: 'created_at'
  },
  updatedAt: {
    type: DataTypes.DATE,
    allowNull: false,
    field: 'updated_at'
  }
 },{
  classMethods:{
    associate: (models) => {
      PurchaseOrder.belongsTo(models.masterPurchaseOrders,{
        foreignkey: 'master_purchase_order_id'
      });
    },
    associate: (models) => {
      PurchaseOrder.belongsTo(models.supplier,{
        foreignkey: 'supplier_id'
      });
    },
  },
}, {
    timestamps: true,
    paranoid: false,
    underscored: true,
    freezeTableName: true,
    tableName: 'purchase_orders'
  });

  return PurchaseOrder;
}
```

Purchase Order Controller:

```
"using strict";
const purchaseOrder = require('../models/').purchase_orders;
const Supplier = require('../models/').supplier;
const Master = require('../models/').masterPurchaseOrders;

module.exports= {
  index(req, res) {
    purchaseOrder
      .findAll({
        include:[Supplier, Master]
      })
      .then((masters) => {
        res.status(200).json(masters);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        res.status(500).json(error);
      });
  },
  create(req, res) {
    purchaseOrder
      .create(req.body)
      .then( master => {
        res.status(200).json(master);
      })
      .catch( error => {
        res.status(500).json(error);
      });
  },
};
```

If I only include the model supplier in the function findall(). I get the data from the purchase and the data from the supplier.
But when I include the model master purchase order. I get an empty json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you overwrite the `associate` property of your `classMethods`, and only the second `associate()` function will be executed.

You should move both of your association definitions into one function:

```
classMethods:{
    associate: (models) => {
        PurchaseOrder.belongsTo(models.masterPurchaseOrders,{
            foreignkey: 'master_purchase_order_id'
        });
        PurchaseOrder.belongsTo(models.supplier,{
            foreignkey: 'supplier_id'
        });
    },
},
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to get an object with child relation? As I'm using findOne method of parent model which having hasMany relation but retrying only single object of parent table and didnt get any relation.

Answer (score 2):

Can you do the following

```
purchaseOrder
      .findAll({
        include:[{model: Supplier, required:true}, {model: Master, required : false}]
      })
```